# bootstrap nav-collapse wont show icon when collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="target1">
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
<span class="icon-white icon-chevron-down"></span>
</a>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div  class="brand" style="padding-left:50px"><strong>abc.def </strong></div>
<div class="brand"  style="padding-left:40px"><strong>1234</strong></div>   
<ul class="nav">
<li style="padding-left:25px"><a href="contact.php"><i class="icon-white icon-envelope"></i><strong>Mail Us</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="/livechat/client.php"><i class="icon-white icon-comment"></i><strong>Live Chat</strong></a></li>
<li class="hidden-phone"><a href=""><i class="icon-white icon-globe">     </i><strong>Remote</strong></a></li>
<div class="nav nav-collapse">  
<li><a href="#approach"><strong>Our Approach</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="#services"><strong>Services</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="#aboutus"><strong>About Us</strong></a></li>

</ul>
    </div></div>
</nav>
```

in this bootstrap navbar will collapse but the glyphicon wont showup when minimised..  Any Ideas or Suggestions..?

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using? Can you put your code as a fiddle?

Comment: I think you're missing the <span class="icon-bar"></span> parts. Edit: I think you're using Bootstrap 2, right?

Comment: using bootstrap 2.3.2 ....and i didnt miss the span as you see in the code...:-)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/parvvee/a7PNP fiddle for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your items were a little out of order, and you were missing the `<a class="btn btn-navbar"...` parts.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="target1">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">

        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>

        <a class="brand" style="padding-left:50px"><strong>abc.def </strong></a>

        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="contact.php"><i class="icon-white icon-envelope"></i><strong>Mail Us</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="/livechat/client.php"><i class="icon-white icon-comment"></i><strong>Live Chat</strong></a></li>
                <li class="hidden-phone"><a href=""><i class="icon-white icon-globe"></i><strong>Remote</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#approach"><strong>Our Approach</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#services"><strong>Services</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#aboutus"><strong>About Us</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div><!-- container -->
</div><!-- navbar-inner -->
```

and don't forget the collapsable plugin...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.collapse').collapse();
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you but i am confused because i can use <a >  whereever i want in the navbak....

Comment: Their rules, not mine. ;) And, yeah, Bootstrap's nav is a confusing pain in the butt. Glad I could help.

Comment: Hey tim, again went wrong......... code is same but it wont show up..let me see if using bootstrap 3.0 helps

Comment: I tested the code and it works as it should. Perhaps there's another issue somewhere?...